# building kernel with non-retpoline compiler

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, make

I am trying to build rtl wifi driver on Ubuntu and when I use `make` command, it gives me this message

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
arch/x86/Makefile:245: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: what is your output for `cmake --version && build-essential --version && libgtk-3-dev --version && gir1.2-gtk-3.0 --version && libgtk-3-0 --version` ?

Answer (score 6):

Change [CONFIG_RETPOLINE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RETPOLINE.html) to n.

Run `make menuconfig`. Navigate to `Processor type and features`, and uncheck `Avoid speculative indirect branches in kernel`.

Note that your kernel can be exposed to kernel-to-user data leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
sudo make
```

instead of `make`?

`make` gave me that retpoline error. not present with a `sudo make` instruction.