# how to build ubuntu for arm64? (how to give ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE variable to `debian/rules` command)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compiling

I downloaded ubuntu source by `git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git`.
and according to `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel` and the included build process for arm, I did this:

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean  
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

I had exported `ARCH=arm64  CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf`  or
`ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-` before the commands, or with the command but it ended with errors at the end.  One of the error message was `You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler` and I saw I can fix it by changing configuration([building kernel with non-retpoline compiler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145943/building-kernel-with-non-retpoline-compiler)). So I tried

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

But it asks me `Do you want to edit config: amd64/config.flavour.generic?` when I'm doing it for arm64 architecture. I tried giving ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE option but it always asks me if I want to change amd64 configuration. How can I give it the ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE option for this `fakeroot debian/rules` build method?

p.s. my toolchain info.

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Linaro GCC 7.5-2019.12) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

or

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) 9.2.1 20191025
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: May be good to ask here https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoKeR thanks it seems so. I asked it there and when I get answer, I'll cross link so that people can get answer anyway. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656263/how-to-build-ubuntu-for-arm64-how-to-give-arch-and-cross-compile-variable-to)

Comment: The answer is here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656263/how-to-build-ubuntu-for-arm64-how-to-give-arch-and-cross-compile-variable-to